# Image in modal window with Ajax XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I needed to create a button which is able to load different types of content (text, images, videos etc) into a modal popup window using Ajax. (I'm not allowed to use any frameworks etc, just Ajax/HTML/CSS/JS).
Up until now it worked fine with text, but I can't seem to get it working with images. I used many kinds of code which I found online, but all of them have the same problem.
I'm using Chrome, but tested on Edge and Firefox as well.

Problem:
The modal window pops up, but is empty.

Here is the html-code:

```
<div id="lightbox-div" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="demo"></img>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="modal_button">Click me</button>
```

Here is the JS-Code:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("modal_button");
var modal = document.getElementById("lightbox-div");

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("img").src = 
         "data:"+xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")+";base64," + 
         btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(
         xhr.response)));
      }
    }
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  xhr.open("GET","fail.jpg",true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Also is there a possibility to get different kinds of content with only one div-element?

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: `<img id="demo">`  </ img >  there's no end tag for img HTML5 element. Also you are calling for an element with the #id of "img". The only `<img>` you have ha an #id of "demo" `document.getElementById("img").src = ...` should be: `document.getElementById("demo").src = ...`

Comment: using Chrome 62.. win7 here - when I tried basically the code above with a 334kb bmp file, it failed with an error in the console. "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" along with a stack-trace. Hmmm. I then tried to pull an 18kb jpg and I got the image I asked for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the basic act of requesting a file, base64 encoding the data before applying a header to it and setting it as the src of an image works fine. As is typical, error-checking i minimal to non-existant and left as an exercise to the reader.

You'll note I've now used a seperate function to do the ajax request which will call one of two user specified callbacks.

1. You wont have to repeat the xmlHttpRequest stuff everywhere you
   want to ajax another reource now.
2. The `onBtnClicked` function shows a neat way of asking for some
   data and defining what you'll do with it when you do (or dont!) get
   it.
3. You may have identified `ajaxGetArrayBuffer` as a good candidate for
   modification. What if I want XML back? How about plain text? Do I
   have to write one function for each type of data I want back? No.
   What if a 4th input to the function was declared - an input that was
   optional, but could be used for niceness.

Perhaps:

`ajaxGetArrayBuffer(url, onLoad, onError, resultType)`

Provided the user supplied a 4th input, you could just set that. Otherwise, just leave it blank.

`resultType !== undefined` (yes, that is 2 = symbols) should help you here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    byId('modal_button').addEventListener('click', onBtnClicked, false);
}

function ajaxGetArrayBuffer(url, onLoad, onError)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onload = function(){onLoad(this);}
    ajax.onerror = function(){onError(this);}
    ajax.open("GET",url,true);
    ajax.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    ajax.send();
}

function onBtnClicked(evt)
{
    byId('lightbox-div').style.display = 'block';
//  ajaxGetArrayBuffer('gfx07.jpg', onAjaxLoaded, onAjaxFailed);    /// ** WORKS FINE - 18kb jpg **
    ajaxGetArrayBuffer('s13.bmp', onAjaxLoaded, onAjaxFailed);      /// *** FAILS - 334kb bmp **
    function onAjaxLoaded(ajax)
    {
        byId('demo').src =  "data:"+ajax.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")+";base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(ajax.response)));
    }
    function onAjaxFailed(ajax)
    {
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<div id="lightbox-div" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img id="demo"></img>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="modal_button">Click me</button>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```